# How can I remotely debug tomcat 7.0 on windows?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat

There is no catalina.bat so I can't pass debugger port. Also its hard to find help on apache site. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no catalina.bat? My install of Tomcat 7.0.14 has one (in the `bin` directory, of course).

Comment: The only files in bin folder are: bootstrap.jar
tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat7.exe
Tomcat7w.exe

Comment: Try to install the zip file version. Maybe you installed using the windows service installer, which doesn't install everything.

Comment: This helps, though this is not the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass JVM options using *JvmOptions* parameter:

```
tomcat.exe //TS// ++JvmOptions -Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

or

```
tomcat.exe //RS// ++JvmOptions -Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this entirely solves your problem, but the [Apache Tomcat Windows Service HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) explains how to use Tomcat7.exe and Tomcat7w.exe, and what the command line parameters are.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin>Tomcat7.exe --JvmOptions=-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
[2012-07-28 21:16:44] [error] Unrecognized cmd option --JvmOptions=-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
[2012-07-28 21:16:44] [error] Invalid command line arguments
[2012-07-28 21:16:44] [error] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 1 (Failed to parse command line arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the parameters in the tomcat monitor tray tool? There ist a configure dialog with a "Java" and a "Startup" tab where parameters can be passed to the service.